# XAML Data Binding Enabled from Function | Lock View Conditionally

Tags: wpf, xaml, xamarin, data-binding

Richt now I am checking in the code behind whether or not the controls in the view should be enabled:

```
public void Lock() {
    if (_status != 40 && _status != 60)
    {
        txt1.isEnabled = false;
        txt2.isEnabled = false;
        txt3.isEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

However, for pages with lot's of controls, this is a hassle. Is it possible to achieve the same with Data Binding? Something like this:

```
public void isEnabled() {
    if (_status != 40 && _status != 60)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

And then bind the controls to this function? (Sometimes the conditions for enabling/disabling a view are not as simple as in the example. It should be possible to do quite complex conditions.)

This program is developed with Xamarin. It should not make a difference for WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a property

```cs
public bool isEnabled 
{
    get 
    {
      if (_status != 40 && _status != 60)
          return false;
      else
          return true;
    }
}
```

if you want your UI to update dynamically, you will need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and call `PropertyChanged("isEnabled")` whenever `_status` changes

Comment: So easy, yet I couldn't come up with that solution. Thanks!

Comment: `get { return (_status == 40 || _status == 60); }`